# Recycler not updating list

Tags: kotlin

I have a working recyclerview, sets data perfectly for the first time. However, I try to insert a new item and notify the recyclerview but seems data is not added to list and as such recyclerview is not updated. I don't understand how the list is possibly the same before and after addition of an item.

```
val recyclerView = binding.recyclerViewMessageDetails
val adapter = SmsDetailAdapter(viewmodel, this@SmsDetailActivity, binding.etMessage)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@SmsDetailActivity)  
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

My Adapter:

```
class SmsDetailAdapter(var viewModel: MyViewModel, var activity: Activity, var 
etMessage: AppCompatEditText) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SmsDetailAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

lateinit var view: View
var smsMessages: MutableList<SmsDetail> = mutableListOf()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.displaysmsdetail, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return smsMessages.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val sms = smsMessages[position]

    if (sms.state == "Received") {
        val theView = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.receivedTextView)
        theView.setText(sms.body)
        holder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.receivedcard).visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    
}


class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}


fun setData(newSmsMessages: List<SmsDetail>) {
    smsMessages = newSmsMessages as MutableList<SmsDetail>
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun updateItem(newItem: SmsDetail, recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    Log.d("updateItem-------", "initall: ${newItem}")
    Log.d("updateItem-------", "initall: ${smsMessages.size}")
    try {
        smsMessages.add(newItem)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("updateItem-------", "initall: ${e.message}")
    }
    Log.d("updateItem-------", "initall: ${smsMessages.size}")
    notifyItemInserted(smsMessages.size + 1)
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(smsMessages.size - 1)
}


}
```

And the following are the logs when I try to update an item

```
initall: SmsDetail(body=ai, phoneNumber=0725641526, timestamp=9999999999999999, 
state=Sent, type=2, formattedTimestamp=4:03 PM, status=Sent - 1697535171691)
initall: 340
initall: null
initall: 340
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two problems. When we look at the logs, we see that it has not actually added to the list. However, even if it had added to the list, the new element would not appear in the recyclerview. The reason of this

```
notifyItemInserted(smsMessages.size + 1)
```

You are notifying an element of the list that does not exist. After adding, you need to notify recyclerview that you added the last one to the end of the list.

```
notifyItemInserted(smsMessages.size - 1)
```

We solved the Recyclerview update problem.

But if you still cannot add an element to the list (Log says you can't add)

```
var smsMessages: MutableList<SmsDetail> = mutableListOf()
```

to

```
var smsMessages: MutableList<SmsDetail> = arrayListOf()
```

You should be able to add like this.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it as last element.

```
notifyItemInserted(smsMessages.size + 1)
```

to

```
notifyItemInserted(smsMessages.size - 1)
```

---

```
fun updateItem(newItem: SmsDetail, recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        Log.d("updateItem-------", "initall: ${newItem}")
        Log.d("updateItem-------", "initall: ${smsMessages.size}")
        try {
            smsMessages.add(newItem)
           
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("updateItem-------", "initall: ${e.message}")
        }
        Log.d("updateItem-------", "initall: ${smsMessages.size}")
        notifyItemInserted(smsMessages.size - 1)
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(smsMessages.size - 1)
    }
```